# Результат из MySQL в JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

Есть такой код:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('my_base2') or die('Не могу выбрать базу данных');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ID<=2";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
        $rows[] = array($row);
    }

    echo json_encode($rows)
?>
```

На выходе получаю результат такого вида:

```
[
    [{
        "ID":"1",
        "telephone_num":"89266677121",
        "date_added":"12.07.2016",
        "nick_name":"Stas",
        "firma":"Xtrun",
        "comment":"Voohoo!",
        "like":"0"
    }],    
    [{
        "ID":"2",
        "telephone_num":"89263324311",
        "date_added":"12.09.2016",
        "nick_name":"Vovchik",
        "firma":"\u041e\u041e\u041e \u041c\u0438\u0440 \u0412\u0430\u043c",
        "comment":"\u0413\u0430\u0432\u043d\u043e",
        "like":"1"
    }]
]
```

Получается, что внутри одного массива содержаться другие позиции в отдельных массивах. Как создать такую структуру Json:

```
{
    "orderID":12345,"contents":[
        {
            "ID":1,"telephone_num":"453453","nick_name":"Kolya"
        },
        {
            "ID":2,"telephone_num":"2342525","nick_name":"Vova"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Совершенно не ясно откуда возьмется информация `"orderID":12345` - в исходных данных ее нет. А по факту вам надо просто получить меньше полей. может просто из базы выбирать не `*`, а `ID, telephone_num, nick_name` - это кстати к php никакого отношения даже не имеет - просто sql. Ну и дальше чисто текстовыми функциями убрать внешние [] и дописать свой orderId

Comment: 3й код просто для примера. какая структура должна получиться. "дальше чисто текстовыми функциями убрать внешние [] и дописать свой orderId" - Это "научный" метод так сказать? Так вот кстати и интересует вопрос: Если результатов 20 то как их вбить в 1 массив contents?

Comment: ну так если вы из базы выдерите не все, а только 3 поля - то уже практически автоматом получите эту свою структуру. и вот тот orderid как ни крути вам откуда то брать надо. в принципе вам там уже ответили. вдруг даже угадали что вам на самом деле надо ...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделать нужный вам массив и вернуть его

```
$response = [
    'orderID'=>12345,
    'contents'=>[]
];
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $response['contents'][] = [
        'ID'=>$row->ID,
        'telephone_num'=>$row->telephone_num,
        'nick_name'=>$row->nick_name

    ];
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Во блин спасибо! А то я говорю с синтаксисом не знаком поэтому сложно.

Comment: Не за что. Если это то что вам нужно, отметьте ответ как верный.